# PDO::FETCH_ASSOC returns false

Tags: php, mysql, sql, oop, pdo

This is a script that is supposed to search for users in the DB. I have this script split between 4 files: login.class.php, userLookup.php, userLookupDisplay.tpl.php, and userLookup.tpl.php.

The code in these files is as follows:

login.class.php: (this is not the entire class, I cut most of the class out for readability)

```
class login
{
    public function userLookup($email = null, $first_name = null, $last_name = null)
    {
        $where = "";
        $execute = "";
        if(!is_null($email) && !empty($email))
        {
            $where .= "email = :email";
            $execute = array(':email' => $email);
        }

        if(!is_null($first_name) && !empty($first_name))
        {
            $where .= "first_name = :firstName";
            $execute = array(':firstName' => $first_name);
        }

        if(!is_null($last_name) && !empty($last_name))
        {
            $where .= "last_name = :lastName";
            $execute = array(':lastName' => $last_name);
        }

        if (!empty($where))
        {
        $query =$this->_db->prepare("SELECT id, email, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE " . $where);
        $query->execute($execute);
        return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        var_dump($query);
        var_dump($execute);
        }

        elseif(empty($where))
        {
            echo "Please enter at least one search criteria";
        }
    }   
}
```

userLookup.php:

```
session_start();

require_once('inc/config.php');
require_once($loginClassPath);

if (!empty($_SESSION['user_id']) && $_SESSION['role'] == 2)
{
        include('inc/dbConnect.php');
        if ($pdo)
        {
            $loginClass = new login($pdo);
            $userData = null;

            if (isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                $firstName = $_POST['first_name'];
                $lastName = $_POST['last_name'];
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                $userData = $loginClass->userLookup($email, $firstName, $lastName);
                var_dump($userData);
            }

            if (!is_null($userData))
            {
                include($userLookupDisplayTpl);
            }
            else
            {
                include($userLookupTpl);
            }
        }
}
else
{
    header('Location: accessDenied.php');
    die();
}
```

userLookup.tpl.php:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>View Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center;">
        <form method="POST" action="<?= $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']; ?>">
            <? var_dump($userData); ?>
            First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" value=""/><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" value=""/><br>
            Email: <input type="text" name="email" value=""/><br>            
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Get User"/>
        </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

userLookupDisplay.tpl.php:

```
<html>
<head>

<title>View Users</title>
</head>
<body>

<div style="text-align:center;">
    <? var_dump($userData); ?>
    <? echo $userData['id']; ?>
    <? echo $userData['first_name']; ?>
    <? echo $userData['last_name']; ?>
    <p>Return</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

The problem I am having is that `$userData` (in userLookup.php) keeps returning `boolean false` without any errors. Based on the var_dumps it looks like the query itself is being constructed properly so I can't figure out why it's returning false? Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks in advance guys! Also, let me know if you need more info.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some `AND` s between the statements in that `$where` variable ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `login.class.php` you override your array `$execute`, and you need some condition like a `AND` or `OR` to your `WHERE` clause, change your code to:

```
    $where = array();
    $execute = array();

    if(!is_null($email) && !empty($email))
    {
        $where[] = "email = :email";
        $execute[':email'] = $email;
    }

    if(!is_null($first_name) && !empty($first_name))
    {
        $where[] = "first_name = :firstName";
        $execute[':firstName'] = $first_name;
    }

    if(!is_null($last_name) && !empty($last_name))
    {
        $where[] = "last_name = :lastName";
        $execute[':lastName'] = $last_name;
    }

    if (count($where) > 0)
    {

    $where = implode(' AND ', $where);

    $query =$this->_db->prepare("SELECT id, email, first_name, last_name FROM users WHERE " . $where);
    $query->execute($execute);
    return $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    var_dump($query);
    var_dump($execute);
    }
```